# How can GeoServer transform a 'no RHR layer' into a RHR layer?

Tags: geoserver, geojson, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

We are using `GeoServer 2.11.2` and `Mapbox`.

We have many layers that do not follow the **rule of the right hand** and we need to serve them to other application. The problem is that we have to show in a map with `[Mapbox][1]` using the function `addLayer` and this function only shows layers that follow RHR.

Is there any possibility of serving an `RHR` directly with `GeoServer` from a no RHR layer? Or is there other function in `Mapbox` that allow showing these kinds of layers?

I'm using GeoJSON as output format

Comment: I believe that you are using GeoJSON as output format. GeoServer is using the deprecated 2008 version of GeoJSON http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html, perhaps because the new specification dropped also support for all other coordinate systems than EPSG:4326, or in lack of developer time. If Mapbox libraries do not support old style polygons the only alternative might be to use GML output. But does Mapbox support GML?

Comment: as @user30184 suggests GML is a standard and well supported output format, otherwise you will need to fix your input files. Or you can contribute or sponsor a fix to the GeoTools/GeoServer code to enforce the RHR on GeoJSON.